¿Como puedo leer este XML con php 8.3?
Estoy actualizando una aplicación, esta desarrollada en php 5.2 y la estoy pasando a 8.3, para la lectura de ficheros XML utilizaba una libreria llamada 'DOMIT_XML' pero dejo de actualizarse.
https://www.phpclasses.org/package/1468-PHP-A-Document-Object-Model-DOM-compliant-xml-parser.html#information
El XML contiene las caracteristicas de cursos SCROM para una plataforma de formación
Quiero usar simpleXML, pero al leer el fichero siempre da error. Da igual que lo lea directamente a XML como si leo el fichero a string y este string lo paso a XML, da error siempre.
El contenido del fichero es el siguiente


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest identifier="LPD" version="1.0"
 xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" 
 xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2     imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd 
 http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd"> 

  <organizations default="ORG-462EB53F-796C-BD51-7198-71D1A761B7E4">
        <organization identifier="ORG-462EB53F-796C-BD51-7198-71D1A761B7E4">
            <title>WBT APROXIMACI&Oacute;N A LA PROTECCI&Oacute;N DE DATOS</title>
            <item identifier="SCO1" identifierref="z" isvisible="true">
                <title>Introducci&oacute;n</title>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO2" identifierref="a" isvisible="true">
                <title>Introducci&oacute;n General.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO3" identifierref="b" isvisible="true">
                <title>Marco normativo b&aacute;sico.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>             
            <item identifier="SCO4" identifierref="c" isvisible="true">
                <title>Terminolog&iacute;a b&aacute;sica.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a&b</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO5" identifierref="d" isvisible="true">
                <title>Principios de la protecci&oacute;n de datos.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a&b&c</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO6" identifierref="e" isvisible="true">
                <title>Ficheros.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a&b&c&d</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO7" identifierref="f" isvisible="true">
                <title>Medidas de seguridad.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a&b&c&d&e</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO8" identifierref="g" isvisible="true">
                <title>Derechos de los interesados.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a&b&c&d&e&f</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO9" identifierref="h" isvisible="true">
                <title>Agencia Espa&ntilde;ola de Protecci&oacute;n de Datos.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a&b&c&d&e&f&g</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
            <item identifier="SCO10" identifierref="i" isvisible="true">
                <title>Infracciones y sanciones.</title>
                <adlcp:prerequisites type="aicc_script">z&a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h</adlcp:prerequisites>
            </item>
        </organization>
  </organizations>

   <resources>
    <resource identifier="z" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="z/z.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="a" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="a/a.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="b" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="b/b.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="c" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="c/c.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="d" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="d/d.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="e" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="e/e.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="f" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="f/f.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="g" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="g/g.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="h" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="h/h.htm"></resource>
    <resource identifier="i" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="i/i.htm"></resource>
  </resources>
  <numeracion valor="0"></numeracion>
</manifest>



No se si es por el uso de caracteres especiales o porque pero no consigo leerlo, los ficheros siempre tendran una estructura parecida a este que pongo de ejemplo.
este es el código que estoy utilizando en estos momentos


//CARGO XML DESDE UN FICHERO
echo "Cargamos XML desde un fichero<br>";
$cadena_iso = file_get_contents('imsmanifest.xml');
//---------------------------------------------------

$str    =   mb_convert_encoding($cadena_iso, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');    //CONVIERTO A UTF-8
$str    =   html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');            //CONVIERTO LAS ENTIDADES HTML A CARACTERES NORMALES
$str    =   Caracteres_a_indetidades_HTML($str);

$continuar=true;

try {
    // Cargar el XML y registrar el espacio de nombres
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
    //echo "<pre>".print_R($xml, true)."</pre>";
    
    // Obtener los espacios de nombres del nodo <manifest>
    $namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces(true);

    // Verificar si existe el nodo <manifest>
    $manifest = $xml->xpath('//manifest');
    if (!empty($manifest)) {
        $manifest = $manifest[0]; // Obtener el primer nodo <manifest>

        // Extraer los atributos de <manifest>
        $identifier = (string) $manifest['identifier'];
        echo "Identifier: $identifier\n";

        // Mostrar los espacios de nombres obtenidos dinámicamente
        foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
            echo "Namespace [$prefix]: $namespace\n";
        }

        // Registrar los espacios de nombres obtenidos dinámicamente
        foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
            if ($prefix == '') {
                // Espacio de nombres predeterminado
                $xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', $namespace);
            } else {
                $xml->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $namespace);
            }
        }

        // Acceder al valor 'xsi:schemaLocation' usando el prefijo 'xsi' registrado dinámicamente
        if (isset($namespaces['xsi'])) {
            $schemaLocation = $manifest->attributes($namespaces['xsi'])['schemaLocation'];
            echo "xsi:schemaLocation: " . (string) $schemaLocation . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "No se encontró el espacio de nombres 'xsi'.\n";
        }

        // Acceder a los valores 'identifier' de los nodos <item> dentro de organizations->organization->item
        foreach ($xml->organizations->organization->item as $item) {
            echo "Item Identifier: " . (string) $item['identifier'] . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "El nodo 'manifest' <b>NO</b> existe.\n";
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error procesando XML: " . $e->getMessage();
}


function Caracteres_a_indetidades_HTML($str){
    $predefinedEntities = array(
        '&' => '&amp;',
        /*
        '<' => '&lt;',
        '>' => '&gt;',
        '"' => '&quot;',
        "'" => '&apos;'
        */
    );

    // Reemplazar los caracteres especiales usando strtr
    $cadena_convertida = strtr($str, $predefinedEntities);

    return $cadena_convertida;
}



Lo carga correctamente, pero ya desde el principio no soy capaz de ver si existe o no el 'manifest', por lo que el resto es 'absurdo'
Cualquier indicación sera de mucha ayuda
Muchas gracias y un saludo

Hola Félix, te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar una medalla. Con respecto a tu pregunta ¿accidentalmente al copiar el XML has olvidado poner <manifest> o realmente falta en el archivo? ¿podrías presionar [edit] y agregar el código que utilizabas antes?

Hola Marcos, tienes razón, no puse el , acabo de editar la pregunta y ya esta correcto
Gracias

¿Solo necesitas leer el archivo, o también modificarlo y guardarlo?

Por ahora solo leerlo
1.- Ver si es correcto el XML
2.- Ver que exista el nodo 'manifest'
3.- Recoger los atributos del nodo 'manifest' como identifier, version, xmlns, xmlns:adlcp, xsi:schemaLocation
4.- Recorrer los hijos de nodo 'manifest', cmo son 'organizations', 'resources', 'numeracion'.
5.- Ir recorriendo y recopilando cada uno de esos hijos
Gracias por tu interes

¿Podrías compartir el contenido del archivo imsmanifest.xml tal cual? Si es un XML correcto no hay necesidad de aplicar conversiones sobre él. Y si el archivo tiene errores o entidades problemáticas lo mejor es corregir el archivo manualmente, hasta hacerlo un XML válido. Por otra parte, ¿cómo obtienes ese archivo, consultando un Servicio Web, o API o de qué modo? Faltan detalles importantes en tu pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para completarla.

Para que la clase SimpleXMLElement se capaz de procesar tu XML, primero es necesario convertirlo a un XML válido.
Para esto es necesario:

Registrar la entidades HTML presentes en el documento.
Es decir, agregamos al XML:
<!DOCTYPE manifest [
<!ENTITY amp "&#38;">
<!ENTITY Aacute "&#193;">
<!-- etc. -->
]>

Más info:

Wikipedia > List of XML and HTML character entity references
W3C // ENTITIES HTML MathML Set


Corregir los "&" en "adlcp:prerequisites" y convertirlos a entidades HTML (eg: &amp;)
Esto podemos lograrlo usando preg_replace_callback así:
$html = preg_replace_callback('/(<adlcp:prerequisites[^>]+>)([a-z&]+)(<\/adlcp:prerequisites>)/', function ($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_replace('&', '&amp;', $matches[2]) . $matches[3];
}, $html);



Utilizando tu código como base, la solución podría ser la siguiente:
$text = file_get_contents('imsmanifest.xml');

//
$entities = <<<ENTITIES
<!DOCTYPE manifest [
<!ENTITY amp "&#38;">
<!ENTITY Aacute "&#193;">
<!ENTITY aacute "&#225;">
<!ENTITY eacute "&#233;">
<!ENTITY Eacute "&#201;">
<!ENTITY Iacute "&#205;">
<!ENTITY iacute "&#237;">
<!ENTITY Oacute "&#211;">
<!ENTITY oacute "&#243;">
<!ENTITY Uacute "&#218;">
<!ENTITY uacute "&#250;">
<!ENTITY ntilde "&#241;">
<!ENTITY Ntilde "&#209;">
<!-- Agrego una pocas a modo de ejemplo -->
]>
ENTITIES;

try {

    // Agregar las entidades después del cierre de la declaración XML
    $text = str_replace('?>', '?>' . "\n" . $entities, $text);

    // Arreglamos los "&" en "adlcp:prerequisites"
    $html = preg_replace_callback('/(<adlcp:prerequisites[^>]+>)([a-z&]+)(<\/adlcp:prerequisites>)/', function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1] . str_replace('&', '&amp;', $matches[2]) . $matches[3];
    }, $text);

    // Cargar el XML y registrar el espacio de nombres
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($text);
    // echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($xml->saveXml()) . '</pre>';

    // Obtener los espacios de nombres del nodo <manifest>
    $namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces(true);

    // Extraer los atributos de <manifest>
    $identifier = (string) $xml['identifier'];
    echo "Identifier: $identifier\n";

    // Mostrar los espacios de nombres obtenidos dinámicamente
    foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
        echo "Namespace [$prefix]: $namespace\n";
    }

    // Registrar los espacios de nombres obtenidos dinámicamente
    foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
        if ($prefix == '') {
            // Espacio de nombres predeterminado
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', $namespace);
        } else {
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $namespace);
        }
    }

    // Acceder al valor 'xsi:schemaLocation' usando el prefijo 'xsi' registrado dinámicamente
    if (isset($namespaces['xsi'])) {
        $schemaLocation = $xml->attributes($namespaces['xsi'])['schemaLocation'];
        echo "xsi:schemaLocation: " . (string) $schemaLocation . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "No se encontró el espacio de nombres 'xsi'.\n";
    }

    // Acceder a los valores 'identifier' de los nodos <item> dentro de organizations->organization->item
    foreach ($xml->organizations->organization->item as $item) {
        echo "Item Identifier: " . (string) $item['identifier'] . "\n";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error procesando XML: " . $e->getMessage();
}

Resultado:
Identifier: LPD
Namespace []: http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2
Namespace [adlcp]: http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2
Namespace [xsi]: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
xsi:schemaLocation: http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2     imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd      http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd
Item Identifier: SCO1
Item Identifier: SCO2
Item Identifier: SCO3
Item Identifier: SCO4
Item Identifier: SCO5
Item Identifier: SCO6
Item Identifier: SCO7
Item Identifier: SCO8
Item Identifier: SCO9
Item Identifier: SCO10

Demo

Muchas gracias
Me ha sido de gran ayuda

El problema no es la versión de PHP. Lo primero que debes garantizar es que la fuente donde estás obteniendo el XML te devuelva un XML válido. El tuyo no lo es, no sólo porque contiene entidades HTML que lo hacen inválido, sino por la misma estructura.
Probemos con este XML SCORM, el cual sí es válido, para comprobarlo lo puedes copiar y pegar aquí.
Si pasamos ese XML a una cadena llamada $str y luego hacemos esto:
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
//var_dump($xml);
foreach ($xml->organizations->organization->item as $item) 
{
    echo $item->title,PHP_EOL;
}

La salida es correcta:
Playing the Game
Etiquette
Handicapping
Having Fun

Lo puedes comprobar en este fiddle y hacer otras pruebas de lectura.
En definitiva, para que la lectura de cualquier de archivo funcione, dicho archivo debe ser válido. Esto aplica para XML, JSON u otros.

Gracias por tu ayuda interes
El XML es el que se le pasaba anteriormente, pero con la libreria antigua en php. 5.3 y no daba problemas.
Ahora utilizando el fiddle que me dices, veo que tengo varios problemas, que casi se  resumen en uno, que es la utilización del carcter &, tanto en las cadenas de texto donde convierte los caracteres con acentos, eñes... a su codigo HTML y lo que me es mas grabe el uso de cosas como esta 'z&a&b&c' donde el carcter & es un condicionante para el desarrollo de la aplicación, es decir no es un adorno.
No se como continuar, la verdad

Si le quito los & funciona perfectamente lo que me has pasado, pero los necesito...

@FélixMiguelMorenoPolo ¿Cuál es el código que usas para obtener el XML?

@Marcos sospecho que se está manoseando demasiado el archivo .xml, lo cual resulta finalmente en un archivo inválido. He pedido a OP que muestre el contenido original del archivo, el cual, si es válido, se puede pasar directamente a SimpleXMLElement. OP hace una serie de conversiones que podrían ser innecesarias. Y, si hubiera problemas de codificación sería mejor resolverlas a otro nivel, no atacando directamente al contenido del archivo.
